# Why do certain apps always try to install to a specific Google account?

Tags: google-play-store, installation

I have 3 Google accounts on my Android phone: gmail and 2 Google Apps accounts (one at my full-time job and one for my small business).  I want all my apps to install under the gmail account, so I've done the following:

1. Open Play Store
2. Press menu button
3. tap Accounts
4. select the gmail account

When I install some apps, they install to whatever account I've selected in the Accounts menu.

But despite having the gmail account selected, when I try to install certain apps such as My Tracks (by Google) and K-9 Mail, the Play Store says the apps will be installed under the Google Apps account for my full-time job.  How do I force *all* apps to be installed under my gmail account instead?